# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_row() in

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

В интернет нашёл скрипт построения графика по данным MyQSQL.
Скопировал, вставил, пытаясь подставить свои данные. Но выдаёт ошибку "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_row() in".
Ругается именно на

```
    while ($record = $order_result->fetch_row()){
        $all[] =  array(strtotime($record[0]), (float)$record[1], (float)$record[2], (float)$record[3]);
    }
```

Весь код:

```
    $event_id = 3993;

    $order_result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT op.order_id, op.event_places, op.event_id, op.event_date FROM wp_12ae_evpl_orders_places op WHERE op.event_id = $event_id ");
    //$order_result_json = json_decode(json_encode($order_result), true);

    //echo '<pre>', print_r($order_result ), '</pre>';
    
    while ($record = $order_result->fetch_row()){
        $all[] =  array(strtotime($record[0]), (float)$record[1], (float)$record[2], (float)$record[3]);
    }

    echo json_encode($all);
    
    $mysqli->close();
?>

<div id="container2" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px"></div>
<script>
    Highcharts.setOptions({
                lang: {
                    loading: 'Загрузка...',
                    months: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
                    weekdays: ['Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'],
                    shortMonths: ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Март', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Авг', 'Сент', 'Окт', 'Нояб', 'Дек'],
                    exportButtonTitle: "Экспорт",
                    printButtonTitle: "Печать",
                    rangeSelectorFrom: "С",
                    rangeSelectorTo: "По",
                    rangeSelectorZoom: "Период",
                    downloadPNG: 'Скачать PNG',
                    downloadJPEG: 'Скачать JPEG',
                    downloadPDF: 'Скачать PDF',
                    downloadSVG: 'Скачать SVG',
                    printChart: 'Напечатать график'
                }
        });
</script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON('jsonp.php', function (data) {

                // split the data set into voltage and current
                var voltage = [],
                    current = [],
                    active = [],
                    dataLength = data.length,

                i = 0;
                for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
                    voltage.push([
                        data[i][0] * 1000, // the date
                        data[i][1], // voltage
                    ]);

                    current.push([
                        data[i][0] * 1000, // the date
                        data[i][2] // the current
                    ]);
                    
                    active.push([
                        data[i][0] * 1000, // the date
                        data[i][3] // the active power
                    ]);
                }


                // create the chart
                Highcharts.stockChart('container2', {

                    rangeSelector: {
                        selected: 1,
                        buttons: [{
                            type: 'minute',
                            count: 10,
                            text: '10м'
                        }, {
                            type: 'hour',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1час'
                        }, {
                            type: 'hour',
                            count: 6,
                            text: '6час'
                        }, {
                            type: 'day',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1дн'
                        }, {
                            type: 'week',
                            count: 1,
                            text: 'неделя'
                        }, {
                            type: 'month',
                            count: 1,
                            text: 'мес'
                        }, {
                            type: 'year',
                            count: 1,
                            text: 'год'
                        }, {
                            type: 'all',
                            text: 'Всё'
                        }]
                    },

                    title: {
                        text: 'Электросеть'
                    },

                    yAxis: [{
                        labels: {
                            align: 'right',
                            x: -3
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Напряжение'
                        },
                        height: '50%',
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        resize: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }, {
                        labels: {
                            align: 'right',
                            x: -3
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Ток'
                        },
                        top: '52%',
                        height: '20%',
                        offset: 0,
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }, {
                        labels: {
                            align: 'right',
                            x: -3
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Мощьность'
                        },
                        top: '75%',
                        height: '20%',
                        offset: 0,
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }],

                    tooltip: {
                        split: true
                    },

                    series: [{
                        type: 'spline',
                        name: 'Вольт',
                        data: voltage,
                        yAxis: 0
                    }, {
                        type: 'spline',
                        name: 'Ампер',
                        data: current,
                        yAxis: 1
                    }, {
                        type: 'spline',
                        name: 'Ватт',
                        data: active,
                        yAxis: 2
                    }]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Использую CMS wordpress

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb-get_results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_fetch_row() устарел и в версиях php выше 7ой, не используется.

Comment: Тогда проблема ясна. Но чем его заменить?

Comment: Смотря какой API для доступа к MySQL используется. Очевидно, что на аналогичную:  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php